# How to connect to the inverter with motor

Tags: motor, inverter, vfd

I have a motor and a inverter ([CT-2002ES-A75](https://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiQhv_0qeHXAhXHv7wKHd77CeEQFggmMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cutes.com.tw%2Fhtml_en%2Fdownload.php%3Ffile%3DCT2000ES_Manual_English_Version_1.0.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0X1mVFThW6BjXVyoA8cFfX)).

Motor nameplate is:

[image: motor nameplate]

How should I connect the motor to inverter?

What are the special parameter in the inverter that should I change according to the motor?

Answer (score 1):

The VFD model CT2002ES-A75 is listed in the manual as rated for 220 volts or 200-230 volts input. The maximum output voltage will be about 220-230 volts, so the delta connection must be used for the motor. The VFD is probably preset for V/Hz pattern 1 on page 16 of the manual. That is the normal setting for operating the motor at 50 Hz and below. That should be sufficient for basic operation. There are other adjustments that could be made, but you should read the manual and say how much you understand before discussing further. For further discussion, you would need to describe what the motor is driving and what the operating requirements are.

Comment: Thanks @Charles...im using a normal relay for give a forward direction signal. Unfortunately , sometime relay is flickering. I think there are some noises from external input pins. So,my Arduino based control circuit get crazy.any solutions ?

Comment: A VFD can cause a lot of electrical noise in low-voltage, low-power systems like Arduino. Keep Arduino wiring away from VFD input and output wiring. Use shielded cable where indicated in manual. Do not put Arduino in the same enclosure as VFD. Make sure VFD has earth ground connection. Arduino protective earth ground conductor should go to grounding point at service entrance not to VFD chassis or local connection point.